# What is the rated tensile strength of 2000 kcmil stranded copper conductor?

Tags: metallurgy, metals, power-engineering

All the documentations I could find goes upto only 1000 kcmil. Please direct to a reference for larger cables.

Is there a method to extrapolate from smaller cable sizes?

Comment: You need to provide the stranding. This is because RTS depends on the strand diameter. The core of a strand is softer than the outside. Also, the number of layers causes a derating.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the table you're looking for?  [Burndy](http://ecat.burndy.com/Comergent/burndy/documentation/section%20o-reference.pdf), see page O-30 . If I read it correctly, you should be able to plot strength vs cmil for the values in that table and generate a smooth curve which should predict the strength at 2E6 cmil.

### ETA

I took the Burndy data, ran a `lowess` smoother followed by a linear regression and got the coefficients
`tensile = 5.72476410e-02*(cmils) +   4.75077150e+03` , which produces a value for `2E6 cmil` of  `1.1925e+05`  (that's breaking strength in pounds)

Use with caution :-), as that's a serious amount of extrapolation.

I found a value at [PriorityWire](http://www.prioritywire.com/brochures/Utility%20Catalog.pdf) (PDF) which says 34 200  pounds for Aluminum cable.  I suspect that it's rare anyone would go to the incredible expense of using Cu for a strength member, which is why nobody measures the value.  Certainly Cu can support its own weight for any run length you can imagine.

Comment: "Certainly Cu can support its own weight for any run length you can imagine." I dunno, I can imagine a pretty long run length.

Comment: @Ethan48  yes, well,    :-) .  Space elevators and all that.

Comment: indeed if you tried to make a high tension power line of copper the strength/weight would be an issue.  Cost drives it out of that job first though.

Answer (score 0):

That is a big cable. I am making an estimation here, but let's follow along with my cable analysis:

1. `1000 Kcmil` copper cable has 4 layers over the king strand with `61` individual strands
2. `2000 Kcmil` copper cable with 5 layers of the king strand has $n=$`91` individual strands
3. `2000 Kcmil` with `91` strands => each strand $d=$`0.148 in^2`

   - Use $d =\sqrt{ \frac{{\rm Kcmil}}{1000\,n}}$ where $n$ is the strand count.
4. Overall size of the cable is $D=$`1.927 in`

   - Use $D = d (1+2 ( {\rm layers}+1))$
5. Total strand area is $A=$`1.571 in^2`

   - Use $A = n \frac{\pi d^2}{4}$
6. The strand strength factor for aluminum (not pure `-O` spec) is $\rm sf=$`0.965`

   - Use ${\rm sf} = 1.1277 - 1.096 \, d$ (taken from a table in the Alcoa conductor manual and curve-fitted with a line.)
7. I don't have the copper equivalent of the strength factor, but I am assuming it is the same ( approx. similar strength ratio of strand surface to center).
8. The ultimate strength of copper is $\sigma_U=$`62100 psi` for fully hard copper.

   - Use solid copper tables and back-calculate from one strand of `0.162 in` having rated strength `1280 lbs`.
9. The rated strength of `2000 Kcmil` copper cable is **`94100 lbs`**

   - Use $T = ({\rm sf})×A ×\sigma_U$

---

- Reference: http://www.southwire.com/ProductCatalog/XTEInterfaceServlet?contentKey=prodcatsheet46